# how to set the source address of udp broadcast?

Tags: java, udp, broadcast

I have this code to send out a broadcast message over a lan and it was working fine until I installed a virtual machine and i now have a virtual network adapter.

```
  String address = "255.255.255.255";
    try {
        packet.setAddress(InetAddress.getByName(address));
        packet.setPort(59123);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        socket.send(packet);
        ...
```

Now when I try to do the broadcast Wireshark is showing the message being sent from 192.168.56.1 (ip address of virtual adapter)

How would i go about setting the adapter I'd like to use for sending the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DatagramSocket [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket(int,%20java.net.InetAddress)) which takes the local inet address to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

```
clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(0, InetAddress.getByName("IP address"))
```

Here 0 means OS will automatically assign a port for you. Or you can give a port number through which you will send UDP packets.

```
Suppose your ethernet IP address 192.168.1.2
and your wifi IP address is: 192.168.2.2
```

Then Ip address would be 192.168.2.2 if you want to send UDP packets through wifi NIC.